# Regexp to parse a string delimited by number and a colon

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse a string like this

> 1:Tous les 6 mois2:Every 6 months4:Tutti i 6 mesi3:Cada 6 meses

Into an array like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '1:Tous les 6 mois',
    1 => '1',
    2 => 'Tous les 6 mois',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '2:Every 6 months',
    1 => '2',
    2 => 'Every 6 months',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '4:Tutti i 6 mesi',
    1 => '4',
    2 => 'Tutti i 6 mesi',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '3:Cada 6 meses',
    1 => '3',
    2 => 'Cada 6 meses',
  ),
)
```

I tried this

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+):([^\b(\d:)]+)/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

But it stops the capture at the first digit. Parenthesis get interpreted as characters

Another option would be to use

```
preg_split('/(\d):/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
```

But I'm genuinely interested by a preg_match_all solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead like this

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+):(.*?)(?=\d+:|$)/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The look ahead `(?=\d+:|$)` means match the previous token as long as either a digit and colon or the end of the string is present.

Comment: @Touki glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookahead based regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+):((?:(?!\d:).)*)/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

**Note:** You can't place word boundaries `\b` inside of a character class.

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/305133)

Comment: Thanks, it also works, however, can you explain/link me why `\b` can't be used in character classes?

Comment: Because a character class define a set of characters, "one of any that could be matched" and `\b` inside represents a backspace character.